# Neural Network for Recognition of Handwritten Digits in C#

Tags: c#, neural-network, ocr, digits, handwriting-recognition

I've gone through very good code project article about the **Neural Network for Recognition of Handwritten Digits in C#** by a code project contributor named Vietdungiitb.

**Here's the link for the Project :**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143059/Neural-Network-for-Recognition-of-Handwritten-Digi

But, there was a code sample provided and I ran the code but, I had this error '**Format Exception was unhandled**'.

In the Preferences.cs file.

```
private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out double nDefault)
{

       nDefault = Convert.ToDouble(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
       return; 
}
```

Above Code lines produced the run time exception.

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
       at NeuralNetworkLibrary.Preferences.Get(String lpAppName, String lpKeyName, Double&amp;amp; nDefault) in c:\Users\PC_USER\Downloads\Example\Code Project\source\HandwrittenRecognition\NeuralNetworkLibrary\ArchiveSerialization\Preferences.cs:line 178
       at NeuralNetworkLibrary.Preferences.ReadIniFile() in c:\Users\PC_USER\Downloads\Example\Code Project\source\HandwrittenRecognition\NeuralNetworkLibrary\ArchiveSerialization\Preferences.cs:line 109
       at NeuralNetworkLibrary.Preferences..ctor() in c:\Users\PC_USER\Downloads\Example\Code Project\source\HandwrittenRecognition\NeuralNetworkLibrary\ArchiveSerialization\Preferences.cs:line 97
       at HandwrittenRecogniration.Mainform..ctor() in c:\Users\PC_USER\Downloads\Example\Code Project\source\HandwrittenRecognition\HandwrittenRecognition\Mainform.cs:line 66
       at HandwrittenRecogniration.Program.Main() in c:\Users\PC_USER\Downloads\Example\Code Project\source\HandwrittenRecognition\HandwrittenRecognition\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

There's no enough answers provided for this problem. So, I was wondering if anybody had this problem when they ran this project ?

Full Preferences.cs is as follows.

```
using System;

namespace NeuralNetworkLibrary
{
    public class Preferences
    {
        public const int g_cImageSize = 28;
        public const int g_cVectorSize = 29;

        public int m_cNumBackpropThreads;

        public uint m_nMagicTrainingLabels;
        public uint m_nMagicTrainingImages;

        public uint m_nItemsTrainingLabels;
        public uint m_nItemsTrainingImages;

        public int m_cNumTestingThreads;

        public int m_nMagicTestingLabels;
        public int m_nMagicTestingImages;

        public uint m_nItemsTestingLabels;
        public uint m_nItemsTestingImages;

        public uint m_nRowsImages;
        public uint m_nColsImages;

        public int m_nMagWindowSize;
        public int m_nMagWindowMagnification;

        public double m_dInitialEtaLearningRate;
        public double m_dLearningRateDecay;
        public double m_dMinimumEtaLearningRate;
        public uint m_nAfterEveryNBackprops;

        // for limiting the step size in backpropagation, since we are using second order
        // "Stochastic Diagonal Levenberg-Marquardt" update algorithm.  See Yann LeCun 1998
        // "Gradianet-Based Learning Applied to Document Recognition" at page 41

        public double m_dMicronLimitParameter;
        public uint m_nNumHessianPatterns;

        // for distortions of the input image, in an attempt to improve generalization

        public double m_dMaxScaling;  // as a percentage, such as 20.0 for plus/minus 20%
        public double m_dMaxRotation;  // in degrees, such as 20.0 for plus/minus rotations of 20 degrees
        public double m_dElasticSigma;  // one sigma value for randomness in Simard's elastic distortions
        public double m_dElasticScaling;  // after-smoohting scale factor for Simard's elastic distortions
        private IniFile m_Inifile;
        ////////////
        public Preferences()
        {
            // set default values

            m_nMagicTrainingLabels = 0x00000801;
            m_nMagicTrainingImages = 0x00000803;

            m_nItemsTrainingLabels = 60000;
            m_nItemsTrainingImages = 60000;

            m_nMagicTestingLabels = 0x00000801;
            m_nMagicTestingImages = 0x00000803;

            m_nItemsTestingLabels = 10000;
            m_nItemsTestingImages = 10000;

            m_nRowsImages = g_cImageSize;
            m_nColsImages = g_cImageSize;

            m_nMagWindowSize = 5;
            m_nMagWindowMagnification = 8;

            m_dInitialEtaLearningRate = 0.001;
            m_dLearningRateDecay = 0.794328235;  // 0.794328235 = 0.001 down to 0.00001 in 20 epochs 
            m_dMinimumEtaLearningRate = 0.00001;
            m_nAfterEveryNBackprops = 60000;
            m_cNumBackpropThreads = 2;

            m_cNumTestingThreads = 1;

            // parameters for controlling distortions of input image

            m_dMaxScaling = 15.0;  // like 20.0 for 20%
            m_dMaxRotation = 15.0;  // like 20.0 for 20 degrees
            m_dElasticSigma = 8.0;  // higher numbers are more smooth and less distorted; Simard uses 4.0
            m_dElasticScaling = 0.5;  // higher numbers amplify the distortions; Simard uses 34 (sic, maybe 0.34 ??)

            // for limiting the step size in backpropagation, since we are using second order
            // "Stochastic Diagonal Levenberg-Marquardt" update algorithm.  See Yann LeCun 1998
            // "Gradient-Based Learning Applied to Document Recognition" at page 41

            m_dMicronLimitParameter = 0.10;  // since we divide by this, update can never be more than 10x current eta
            m_nNumHessianPatterns = 500;  // number of patterns used to calculate the diagonal Hessian
            String path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Data\\Default-ini.ini";
            m_Inifile = new IniFile(path);
            ReadIniFile();
        }
        public void ReadIniFile()
        {
            // now read values from the ini file

            String tSection;

            // Neural Network parameters

            tSection = "Neural Network Parameters";

            Get(tSection, "Initial learning rate (eta)", out m_dInitialEtaLearningRate);
            Get(tSection, "Minimum learning rate (eta)", out m_dMinimumEtaLearningRate);
            Get(tSection, "Rate of decay for learning rate (eta)", out m_dLearningRateDecay);
            Get(tSection, "Decay rate is applied after this number of backprops", out m_nAfterEveryNBackprops);
            Get(tSection, "Number of backprop threads", out m_cNumBackpropThreads);
            Get(tSection, "Number of testing threads", out m_cNumTestingThreads);
            Get(tSection, "Number of patterns used to calculate Hessian", out m_nNumHessianPatterns);
            Get(tSection, "Limiting divisor (micron) for learning rate amplification (like 0.10 for 10x limit)", out m_dMicronLimitParameter);


            // Neural Network Viewer parameters

            tSection = "Neural Net Viewer Parameters";

            Get(tSection, "Size of magnification window", out m_nMagWindowSize);
            Get(tSection, "Magnification factor for magnification window", out m_nMagWindowMagnification);


            // MNIST data collection parameters

            tSection = "MNIST Database Parameters";

            Get(tSection, "Training images magic number", out m_nMagicTrainingImages);
            Get(tSection, "Training images item count", out m_nItemsTrainingImages);
            Get(tSection, "Training labels magic number", out m_nMagicTrainingLabels);
            Get(tSection, "Training labels item count", out m_nItemsTrainingLabels);

            Get(tSection, "Testing images magic number", out m_nMagicTestingImages);
            Get(tSection, "Testing images item count", out m_nItemsTestingImages);
            Get(tSection, "Testing labels magic number", out m_nMagicTestingLabels);
            Get(tSection, "Testing labels item count", out m_nItemsTestingLabels);

            // these two are basically ignored

            uint uiCount = g_cImageSize;
            Get(tSection, "Rows per image", out uiCount);
            m_nRowsImages = uiCount;

            uiCount = g_cImageSize;
            Get(tSection, "Columns per image", out uiCount);
            m_nColsImages = uiCount;


            // parameters for controlling pattern distortion during backpropagation

            tSection = "Parameters for Controlling Pattern Distortion During Backpropagation";

            Get(tSection, "Maximum scale factor change (percent, like 20.0 for 20%)", out m_dMaxScaling);
            Get(tSection, "Maximum rotational change (degrees, like 20.0 for 20 degrees)", out m_dMaxRotation);
            Get(tSection, "Sigma for elastic distortions (higher numbers are more smooth and less distorted; Simard uses 4.0)", out m_dElasticSigma);
            Get(tSection, "Scaling for elastic distortions (higher numbers amplify distortions; Simard uses 0.34)", out m_dElasticScaling);
        }
        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out int nDefault)
        {
            nDefault = Convert.ToInt32(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
            return;

        }
        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out uint nDefault)
        {
            nDefault = Convert.ToUInt32(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
            return;
        }

        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out double nDefault)
        {
               nDefault = Convert.ToDouble(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
               return;
        }
        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out byte nDefault)
        {

           nDefault = Convert.ToByte(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
           return ;

        }

        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out string nDefault)
        {
            nDefault = m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName);
            return;

        }
        private void Get(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, out bool nDefault)
        {
            nDefault = Convert.ToBoolean(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName));
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What `m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName)` method returns _exactly_ and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: My money on system's and INI file's decimal separator mismatch. Change it in Windows regional settings.

Comment: Rewrite the code to store settings in InvariantCulture, and read settings in InvariantCulture. Always use InvariantCulture for data that should not be presented to the user.

Comment: @SonerGönül hi thank you for the reply. i entered the full Preferences.cs Code in the Question. Can you please tell me what's wrong here.

Comment: @cyberj0g thank you. Can you please further explain how to change these settings ?

Comment: @SimonSvensson thank you. I'm no expert on c# programming.Can you please further provide explanation? for that.

Comment: Convert.ToDouble can accept a second parameter that tells it how the number should be parsed. Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture there. Go through the rest of the code and adapt all serialization and settings accordingly. This will ensure that all numbers are stored as "13.37" instead of local settings, which in your case probably is "13,37"

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem is in the decimal point of the default .ini file.

```
nDefault = Convert.ToDouble(m_Inifile.IniReadValue(lpAppName, lpKeyName), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```